# Nonhomogeneous poisson process simulation

Tags: r, poisson-process

I've been looking at ways to generate a Nonhomogeneous Poisson Process (NHPP) including the nonlinear time transformation (using a rate-1 process and inverting the cumulative rate function). I've also seen the thinning approach.

**QUESTION:** How do you generate the NHPP via thinning?  What are the key differences between the two approaches?  What would make one prefer one method over the other?

---

**CONTEXT**
I am trying to use a non-homogeneous poisson process to simulate the claims next year, the rate varies depending on which month, my rate function is:

```
nhpp_lambda <- function(t) {
  if (t <= 59) {lambda = 20.83}
  else if (t > 59 & t <= 151) {11.02}
  else if (t > 151 & t <= 243) {11.68}
  else if (t > 243 & t <= 334) {26.41}
  else if (t > 334 & t <= 365) {20.83}
}
```

When I try to adopt the thinning approach and run the following code:

```
nhpp_simulate <- function() {
  d <- 0
  X <- 0
  while(X[length(X)] <= 365) {
    U <- runif(1)
    d <- d - log(U)/lambda_star
    U2 <- runif(1)
    if(U2 <= nhpp_lambda(d)/27) {X <- c(X,d)}
  }
  return(X)
}

blahblah <- nhpp_simulate()
```

R gives the error "Error in if (U2 <= nhpp_lambda(d)/27) { : 
  argument is of length zero" but length(U2) is definitely not zero?

Comment: which packages does nhpp_lambda belong to please? It is not NHPP is it?

Answer (score 4):

**Thinning Approach:** (method below by OP's request)
Inefficient when fluctuation in time is large (big $\bar \lambda$ gives a high rejection probability). Possible workaround is to break interval $[0,T]$ into small intervals and pick a $\bar \lambda$ for each interval.

**Nonlinear Time Transformation (inversion) Approach:** [see method here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368968/non-homogenous-poisson-process-with-simple-rates/369093#369093)
Inefficient when $m(t)$ is difficult to invert (requiring numerical search). Possible workaround is to consider a piecewise constant approximation for $\lambda(t)$.

**Generating a NHPP: Thinning Method**
Task: Generate a NHPP $\{N(t),t\ge 0\}$ with rate $\lambda(t)$ on the interval $t\in [0,T]$.
Preparation:
Choose $\bar \lambda$ such that $\lambda(t) \le \bar \lambda$ for all $t\in [0,T]$.
Define the thinning probability $p(t) = \frac{\lambda(t)}{\bar\lambda}$.

Procedure:
Let $I$ be the number of events that occur by time $t$. Then $S(I)$ is the time of the most recent event.
1. $t=0$;$\,I = 0$.
2. Generate $U_1\sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$.
3. Set $t = t - (\text{ln}(U_1)/\bar \lambda)$. If $t>T$, stop; else go to 4.
4. Generate $U_2 \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, independent of $U_1$.
5. If $U_2 \le p(t)$, set $I = I + 1$; $S(I) = t$.
6. Go to step 2.

At the end of the procedure, you have event times and the counting process.

**Validation**
Since for a fixed $t$, $N(t)\sim\text{Poisson}(m(t))$ with mean $m(t) = \int_0^t \lambda(s)ds$, it is easy to validate the results.
1. Ensure the *Dispersion* equals 1.
2. Ensure you match the rate function (arrival or cumulative).

Let $IDC(t) = \frac{\text{Var}(N(t))}{\text{E}[N(t)]}$ which is the *Index of Dispersion* (for counts). For any NHPP, $IDC(t) = 1,\, \forall t$.

The figure below demonstrates the correctness of the procedure.
[image: Dispersion]

The target arrival rate and cumulative arrival rate are given below.
[image: Arrival Rate]

---

Bootleg MATLAB code...

```
function [ EventTimes ] = genNHPP(rate_fh,T,n,dt)
%GENNHPP Generate a NHPP
%   Generates a NHPP, N(t): # of events by time t
% INPUTS
%   rate_fh : function handle for rate (vectorized)
%   T : end of time horizon
%   n : number of sample paths to generate (default n = 1)
% OUTPUTS
%   EventTimes : if n = 1, EventTimes is a vector (length is number of events)
%                if n > 1, EventTimes is a cell array with n rows (# columns is number of events)
%   NumArrived : Number Arrived by time t (time is row, columns are sample paths)

% Input Error Checking ****************************************************
narginchk(2, 4)
if nargin < 3 || isempty(n), n = 1; end % Default is 1 sample path
if nargin < 4 || isempty(dt), dt = 1; end % Default is 1 day
if ~isa(rate_fh,'function_handle')
    error('rate_fh must be a valid function handle')
end
if T <= 0, error('T must be a positive real number'), end
% End (Input Error Checking) **********************************************

% Generate a NHPP 
MaxLambda = max(rate_fh([0:10^-5:T]));
ph=@(t) rate_fh(t)/MaxLambda;
if n ==1 
    % Single Sample Path
    t = 0; Nevents = 0; EventTimes = []; done = false;
    while ~done
        t = t + (-1/MaxLambda)*log(rand());
        if t > T
            done = true;
        else
            if rand()<= ph(t);
                Nevents = Nevents+1;
                EventTimes(Nevents) = t;
            end
        end
    end

else 
    % Multiple Sample Paths
    NumPaths = n; EventTimes = {};
    for path = 1:NumPaths
        t = 0; Nevents = 0; done = false; 
        while ~done
            t = t + (-1/MaxLambda)*log(rand());
            if t > T
                done = true;
            else
                if rand() <= ph(t);
                    Nevents = Nevents+1;
                    EventTimes{path,Nevents} = t;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!! I am not extremely familiar with coding in matlab, but i read through the steps in the procedure you provided, i think thats what i tried to do myself, is something wrong with my code?

Comment: if I change my rate function to:
`nhpp_lambda <- function(t) {

  if (t > 0 && t <= 59) {lambda = 20.83}

  else if (t > 59 && t <= 151) {lambda = 11.02}

  else if (t > 151 && t <= 243) {lambda = 11.68}

  else if (t > 243 && t <= 334) {lambda = 26.41}

  else if (t > 334 && t <= 365) {lambda = 20.83}

  else if (t > 365) {lambda = 0}

return(lambda)

  }`
then the code can run, am I allowed to do this?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by are you 'allowed'?   What is length of  `nhpp_lambda(d)/27` ?  I'm not very good with R so I'm not sure how to help.  Maybe try a script instead of a function and manually increment loop so you can evaluate step by step and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: If i dont add that extra bit to my rate function, for some reason my d becomes larger than 365